# How can I access current theme colors?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that renders some HTML (from an RSS/Atom feed) in a `WebBrowser` control. In order to make this HTML look more native, I run it through a simple mobilizer which makes the layout, font, images, etc. look more native by rewriting the HTML structure and setting some CSS.

This works fine. I would, however, like to make sure the CSS the mobilizer generates applies the colors from the user's current theme to the background, text, links, etc. While I can apply theme colors in a XAML document, I have not found a way to get these colors from C#. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the accent colours as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769545%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

```
// Determine the accent color.
Color currentAccentColorHex = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
```

It's not the prettiest method to get the name of the colour, if that's what you want, but you can use this which is compatible with WP7 and WP8.

```
string currentAccentColor = "";

switch (currentAccentColorHex.ToString())
{
    case "#FF1BA1E2": currentAccentColor = "blue"; break;
    case "#FFA05000": currentAccentColor = "brown"; break;
    case "#FF339933": currentAccentColor = "green"; break;
    case "#FFE671B8": currentAccentColor = "pink"; break;
    case "#FFA200FF": currentAccentColor = "purple"; break;
    case "#FFE51400": currentAccentColor = "red"; break;
    case "#FF00ABA9": currentAccentColor = "teal (viridian)"; break;

    // Lime changed to #FFA2C139 in Windows Phone OS 7.1.
    case "#FF8CBF26": 
    case "#FFA2C139": currentAccentColor = "lime"; break;

    // Magenta changed to # FFD80073 in Windows Phone OS 7.1.
    case "#FFFF0097": 
    case "#FFD80073": currentAccentColor = "magenta"; break;

    // #FFF9609 (previously orange) is named mango in Windows Phone OS 7.1.
    case "#FFF09609": currentAccentColor = "mango (orange)"; break;

    // Mobile operator or hardware manufacturer color
    default: currentAccentColor = "custom eleventh color"; break;
}

// Write the current accent color.
textBlock2.Text = "accent color = " + currentAccentColor;
```